# Message isn't received by chrome.runtime.onmessage handler between background page and content script

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension which observes web-page events and acts on those.

- There is a message communication between content-script(that is injected using executescript function) and background page.
- Logs assure that message communication using chrome.runtime.sendmessage is been received successfully.
- But there is one scenario where the message is not been received by the handler, which is **open a new window and open the required URL.**
- With this specific scenario, I am not able to see the message been delivered to the OnMessage event handler

UPDATE:
I am updating code snippet following MVCE(it would be of minimal code snippet

```
//We inject scripts to the background page as below:
            let options = { frameId: frameId,file:"Background.js"};
                    let scriptReturn = await new Promise((resolve) =>
                    {
                        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, options, (result) =>
                        {
                            if (!result || result.length == 0)
                            {
                                logging.error("[Script Insertion] Script error while inserting script: " + chrome.runtime.lastError.message, source);
                                resolve(undefined);
                            }
                            else
                                resolve(result[0]);
                        });
                    });
                    
///////We call the function which sends message to background script as below:

//If not top frame, send message to parent with our id, only on visible iframe in case frameElement is accessible 
if (window !== top && (!window.frameElement || window.frameElement && window.frameElement.style.display != "none"))
{
    if (Obj.matchFrameByIndex) 
    {
        //Try to find out which frame id we are for our parent
        for (var i = 0; i < parent.frames.length; ++i)
            if (parent.frames[i] === window)
            {
                console.log("Calling matchframeindex")
                Obj.matchFrameByIndex(scriptInfo.frameId, scriptInfo.parentFrameId, i);
                break;
            }
    }
}


/////Background.js

    this.matchFrameByIndex = function (frameId, parentFrameId, index) {
        /// <summary>Use (i)frame name to match a (i)frame tag with its actual document.</summary>
        /// <param name="frameId" type="Int" optional="false">Id of the child (i)frame</param>
        /// <param name="parentFrameId" type="Int" optional="false">Id of the parent (i)frame</param>
        /// <param name="index" type="Int" optional="false">Index of the child on parent's frame collection</param>

        console.log(`[${(new Date()).toISOString()}]`+"Setting (I)FRAME id. child: " + frameId + ", parent: " + parentFrameId + ", index: " + index );
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
            command: commands.MATCH_FRAME,
            frameId: frameId,
            parentFrameId: parentFrameId,
            index: index
        });
    };
    
    
////The same class has message handler been added as listener as below

 function onMessageHandler(msg, sender, sendResponseCallback) {
        /// <summary>Receives messages from the background page</summary>
        /// <param name="msg" type="Any" optional="true">The message sent by the calling script.</param>
        /// <param name="sender" type="Object" optional="false"></param>
        /// <param name="sendResponseCallback" type="Function" optional="true">Function to call after processing the message</param>

        // The message is only valid if there is a command property
        if (msg && msg.command) {
            console.log(`[${(new Date()).toISOString()}]`+"Grabber: Message received", msg);

            switch (msg.command) {
                case commands.MATCH_FRAME:
                    // Set the id of a child iframe
                    if (typeof (setIdToMatchedFrame) == "function")
                        setIdToMatchedFrame(msg.childFrameId, msg.childFrameIndex);
                    else
                        _this.logError("Ignoring setting of id, the function setIdToMatchedFrame() was not found.");
                    break;
                default:
                    console.log("Unknown command in message: " + msg.command);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Listen for messages from background script
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(onMessageHandler);
}
```

Methods tried:

- I had tried moving  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(onMessageHandler); to the constructor
- On failure to receive the message, tried resending it.Still doesn't help

Any thoughts why in specific scenario message not been received?

Comment: You need to add a proper [MCVE](/help/mcve) to questions about extensions, otherwise we have to waste time guessing. Judging by the current description you send a message from the background script before the content script has been actually executed. This can happen if you didn't specify `runAt: 'document_start'` in executeScript and the page was still loading, but there could be other reasons as well, which is why it's important to show [MCVE](/help/mcve).

Comment: @wOxxOm,Thanks for your reply. But that doesn't help, here the issue happens occasionally.I had validated script injection happens before message passing so that synching isn't an issue.
-On opening new window and load the web-page,message passing happens whenever it detects I-Frame
-There is a log stating message is been sent from background page to injected script but unfortunately not received by OnMessage event handler.

Not sure whether it is Chrome.runtime API specific issue?

Comment: I don't see how you run (inject/declare) those content scripts so I can't help further.

Comment: Okie @wOxxOm
 .Here is the pseudo code:
`chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, options, (result) =>
      {
       
      });
Here options is an object that is:
options.source="File1.js"//for n number of source files it will be a loop'

This is the way I inject code into the tab.

Comment: See my first comment, it suggests using `runAt: 'document_start'` in executeScript.

Comment: Yup,i did try that but it doesn't seem to be working.@wOxxOm

Comment: I still don't see an [MCVE](/help/mcve), only bits and pieces from which it's impossible to see the problem. For example, your background script uses chrome.runtime.sendMessage but it won't send to a content script because you should use chrome.tabs.sendMessage and specify a tab id.